# Phalcon Gettext getLocale() returns false

Tags: php, phalcon, gettext

I have 3 translation files (hu, en, it) but when I tried to translate to "it" the getLocale() returns with false. The "hu" and "en" works well.

My `getTranslation()` function is in the common:

```
php
protected function getTranslation()
    {
        if (!function_exists('gettext')) {
            throw new \Phalcon\Exception('There\'s no gettext extension');
        }

        if (!\is_file(APP_PATH . '/locales/' . $this->selectedLanguageCode . '/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo')) {
            throw new \Phalcon\Exception('There\'s no ' . APP_PATH . '/locales/' . $this->selectedLanguageCode . '/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo' . ' file');
        }

        $translate = new \Phalcon\Translate\Adapter\Gettext([
            'category'      => LC_MESSAGES,
            'locale'        => $this->selectedLanguageCode . '.UTF8',
            'defaultDomain' => 'messages',
            'file'          => 'messages',
            'directory'     => APP_PATH . '/locales/',
        ]);

        return $translate;
    }
```

I wrote some rows to debug before it returns:

```
php
print 'locale: ' . $this->selectedLanguageCode . '.UTF8' . '<br />';
var_dump($translate->getLocale());
die();

return $translate;
```

When I choose `hu`, it says:

```
    locale: hu_HU.UTF8
    string(10) "hu_HU.UTF8"
```

When I choose "en", it says:

```
    locale: en_US.UTF8
    string(10) "en_US.UTF8"
```

But when I choose `it`, it says:

```
locale: it_IT.UTF8
bool(false)
```

I tried to regenerate the English and italian mo files wit poEdit, but the problem is same. In English is working, but italian not.

The mo files locate in

```
/app/locales/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
/app/locales/it_IT/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
```

The mo file for English is:

```
������������,������<�������P������Q���j��e����������������������������A T világa�Project-Id-Version: app 1.0
Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: notesz@xyz.xyz
POT-Creation-Date: 2019-03-31 15:19+0200
PO-Revision-Date: 2019-03-31 17:02+0200
Language-Team: 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Generator: Poedit 2.2.1
Last-Translator: 
Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);
Language: en_US
�T Group�
```

The mo file for italian is:

```
������������,������<�������P������Q���j��e����������������������������A T világa�Project-Id-Version: app 1.0
Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: notesz@xyz.xyz
POT-Creation-Date: 2019-03-31 15:19+0200
PO-Revision-Date: 2019-03-31 17:00+0200
Language-Team: 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Generator: Poedit 2.2.1
Last-Translator: 
Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);
Language: it_IT
�Il mondo di T
```

Comment: Have you installed the Italian language pack for your operating system? Gettext only works for locales you have installed

Comment: @Joni I didn't. And that was the problem.
Thanks fo your help